# Отметка найденных вхождений

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал функцию поиска по каталогу.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы каждое совпадение в строке отмечалось, например, красным цветом.
Понимаю, что нужно найти подстроку и заменить её на такую же, с обёрткой и классом, например `.selected-text`, но не получается реализовать, подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему.

```
$(document).ready(function() { // живой поиск по каталогу
  var filter  = $('.filter__search');

  $(filter).keyup(function () {
    var filterText = $(this).val();

    if (filterText === '' || isNumeric(filterText) || filterText.length < 3) {
      $('.tree-block__item').hide();
    } else {
      $('.tree-block__item').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filterText, 'i')) < 0) {
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        }
      });
    }
  });

  function isNumeric(n) { // проверка на число
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
 $("p").each(function() {
    var $str = 'sit';
        var text = $(this).text();
        text = text.replace($str, "<span style='background-color:yellow'>"+$str+"</span>");
        $(this).html(text);
        });
```

Comment: Так будет вся строка обрамляться в тег, а мне нужно чтобы по мере набора в строке поиска совпадения подсвечивались.  Типо, как здесь https://euroauto.ru/auto/cars/acura/mdx/mdx_2001-2006/

Comment: Совпадения могут быть не только в начале строки, но и в середине и в конце!